# How to view sent messages in Mutt using the default mbox format?

Tags: mutt, neomutt

How do I view the record of sent messages in NeoMutt?
How do I do so using the default values of the following variables:

```
record=~/sent
mbox_type=mbox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you launch NeoMutt you should be in your "inbox"...
In my NeoMutt program the 'c' key is bound to the "change-folder" command.
Notice that is is lowercase 'c'.
Key bindings are case sensitive.
NeoMutt should prompt you to specify a "mailbox" file to open...
In my case this file is located at /home/r/sent and this is a plain text file.
I am using the default mbox format for email message storage...
The value of the muttrc variable "mbox_type" is "mbox" by default.
Which means that in your muttrc file, if you do not set the value of this variable, then its value is "mbox".

I was having the following problem when issuing the "change-folder" command and specifying the path to my /home/r/sent file...
NeoMutt would complain that this file is "not a mailbox file" and therefore I was unable to view my sent messages.
The reason for this was that the owner of this file got changed to root at some point, presumably when I was messing around trying to figure out how to even open this file to view my sent messages.

The owner of this file needs to be you, and the owner of this file needs to have read and write privileges to this file.
Notice that the NeoMutt program runs with your own user permissions.

Issue the "change-folder" command by pressing the 'c' key or whatever key is bound to the "change-folder" command in your case.
Specify the path to your /home/r/sent file.
Then to go back to your "inbox" mailbox file from viewing your sent mailbox file, you could close NeoMutt and launch again.